# Plot an Integral of NDSolve solution

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have a problem with plotting the integral of an NDSolve solution.

I have attached the code for a simple 2nd order linear ODE to be solved by NDSolve and then to be integrated by NIntegrate.

I would you appreciate if you could give me a help to overcome the problem.

My best regards.

Hadi

```
f := NDSolve[{x''[t] + 2 x'[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == -4}, 


x, {t, 0, 2}]

g[t_] := NIntegrate[Exp[y*Evaluate[x[t] /. f]], {y, 1, 10}]

Plot[g[t], {t, 0, 2}]
```

**And hear are the errors**

NDSolve::dsvar: 0.00004085714285714285` cannot be used as a variable. >>

ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{x[0.0000408571]+2 (x^[Prime])[0.0000408571]+(x^[Prime][Prime])[0.0000408571]==0,x[0]==1,(x^[Prime])[0]==-4},x,{0.0000408571,0,2}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand E^(y (x[0.0000408571]/. NDSolve[{x[<<1>>]+Times[<<2>>]+(<<1>>^(<<1>>))[<<1>>]==0,x[0]==1,(x^[Prime])[0]==-4},x,{0.0000408571,0,2}])) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{1,10}}. >>

NDSolve::dsvar: 0.00004085714285714285` cannot be used as a variable. >>

ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{x[0.0000408571]+2 (x^[Prime])[0.0000408571]+(x^[Prime][Prime])[0.0000408571]==0,x[0]==1,(x^[Prime])[0]==-4},x,{0.0000408571,0,2}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand E^(y (x[0.0000408571]/. NDSolve[{x[<<1>>]+Times[<<2>>]+(<<1>>^(<<1>>))[<<1>>]==0,x[0]==1,(x^[Prime])[0]==-4},x,{0.0000408571,0,2}])) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{1.,10.}}. >>

NDSolve::dsvar: 0.04085718367346938` cannot be used as a variable. >>

General::stop: Further output of NDSolve::dsvar will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{x[0.0408572]+2 (x^[Prime])[0.0408572]+(x^[Prime][Prime])[0.0408572]==0,x[0]==1,(x^[Prime])[0]==-4},x,{0.0408572,0,2}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

General::stop: Further output of ReplaceAll::reps will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand E^(y (x[0.0408572]/. NDSolve[{x[<<1>>]+Times[<<2>>]+(<<1>>^(<<1>>))[<<1>>]==0,x[0]==1,(x^[Prime])[0]==-4},x,{0.0408572,0,2}])) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{1,10}}. >>

General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::inumr will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

Answer (score 4):

A useful piece of advice. Before putting many commands in the same cell, try to run each one individually to make sure that there are no errors. This time it was the first NDSolve causing something. The following code works

```
f1 = NDSolve[{x''[t] + 2 x'[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == -4}, 
  x, {t, 0, 2}]
Plot[x[t] /. f1, {t, 0, 2}]
```

And then,the numerical integration and its plot

```
g[t_] := NIntegrate[Exp[y*Evaluate[x[t] /. f1]], {y, 1, 10}]
Plot[g[t], {t, 0, 2}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. However when I still have problem with this code:

f[a_] := NDSolve[{a*x''[t] + 2 x'[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, 
   x'[0] == -4}, x, {t, 0, 2}]
g[t_] := NIntegrate[Exp[y*Evaluate[x[t] /. f[1]]], {y, 1, 10}]
Plot[g[t], {t, 0, 2}]

The errors:

NDSolve::dsvar: 0.00004085714285714285` cannot be used as a variable. >>

...

Comment: Observe that I have not used the := but rather the = in the solution I proposed

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `NIntegrate`:

```
X = NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + 2 x'[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1,x'[0] == -4}, x, {t, 0, 2}]

Plot[Integrate[Exp[y X[t]], {y, 1, 10}],{t,0,2}]
```

[image]

Comment: I understand your points and appreciate for them. I still have not reached my answer.

Please consider the code in which a and b are arbitrary constants and I want to have them utill the finall solution:

f[a_, b_] := 
 NDSolve[{a*x''[t] + b*x'[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == -4}, 
  x[t], {t, 0, 2}]
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. f[1, 2]], {t, 0, 2}]

Now I want to perform integration but the following code does not work:

g[t_] := Integrate[Exp[y*x[t]] /. f[1, 2], {y, 1, 10}]
Plot[g[t], {t, 0, 2}]

Comment: @user14750 as I mentioned previously and you can see in every answer, the issue is the use of the set delayed. That is the := symbol. If you change that to = your code works just fine

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {x''[t] + 2 x'[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == -4};
```

In defining `f` use [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) rather than [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)

```
f = NDSolve[eqns, x, {t, 0, 2}][[1]]
```

[image]

```
g[t_?NumericQ] :=
 NIntegrate[Exp[y*x[t] /. f], {y, 1, 10}]
```

For comparison, the exact solution of the differential equation is

```
sol = DSolve[eqns, x, t][[1]]

(* {x -> Function[{t}, -E^-t (-1 + 3 t)]} *)
```

Verifying the exact solution

```
eqns /. sol // Simplify

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

And the exact expression for `g` is

```
g2[t_] = Integrate[Exp[y*x[t]] /. sol, {y, 1, 10}]

(* (E^(E^-t (1 + (-30 + E^t) t)) (-E^(9 E^-t) + E^(27 E^-t t)))/(-1 + 3 t) *)
```

`g2[t]` has a minimum

```
min = Minimize[g2[t], t] // Simplify

(* {1/3 E^(4/3 - 30/E^(4/3)) (-1 + E^(27/E^(4/3))), {t -> 4/3}} *)

Plot[{g[t], g2[t]}, {t, 0, 2},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{Numeric, Exact}, {0.5, 0.5}],
 Epilog ->
  {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{t, g2[t]} /. min[[2]]]}]
```

[image]